# Could entropy ever be reversed in the universe with infinite time?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, space-expansion, universe, poincare-recurrence

In the far future there will be most likely a point where a maximal state of entropy will be reached in the universe where no more useful work could be done and no structures would form, reaching a state of heat death for the entire universe.

There is the Poincaré recurrence theorem where for a closed universe there could be a reversal of entropy for long-term periods. However in a flat universe with an accelerated expansion it is not so clear that this theorem holds.

However, are there any other mechanisms through which entropy could be ever reversed eventually after reaching heat death? Perhaps something related with quantum fluctuations?

Comment: The ratio of the entire history of the universe to the approximate calculated time of heat death is on the order of $10^{-90}$, which is about a billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion times smaller than the ratio of 1 second to the entire history of the universe since the earliest time the known laws of physics seem like they ought to have worked. (That being on the order of $10^{-17}$). Personally I don't see any reason to suspect we have the *faintest idea what we're talking about* for predictions on that scale, although of course that shouldn't stop us from trying.